# Python - Trying to use a range function to iterate through dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
response = requests.get('https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any?safe-mode&amount=5')
json_string = response.content
    
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string) 

#part of the joke is that this code will sometimes run and sometimes not run. real funny if you ask me.
for i in range(4):
    print("your jokes sir: ", parsed_json['jokes'][i]['setup'], parsed_json['jokes'][i]['delivery'])
```

I import 5 jokes and use a range of 4 to iterate through the separate instances of ['jokes']**[i]**['delivery'], I thought that this would cycle through the  jokes, however it when it runs it doesn't always print the same amount, sometimes it doesnt print anything at all and constantly gives key errors. Wondering how to properly iterate through this
(i have tried changing the range number around and it doesnt seem to have any effect on hitting the key error)

(not using pandas or numpy cause this was for a class assignment and we did not use those for this assignment)

Comment: Probably "sometimes" you don't get 5 jokes back in the answer. You might check it before, but note that  it's better to iterate on the jokes instead of using indices: `for joke in  parsed_json['jokes']: print(joke["setup"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all *jokes* have the `setup` and `delivery` keys (I think the `joke` key and the `setup` `delivery` key pair to be mutually exclusive: there are jokes that consist of a whole joke string and jokes made of a setup and delivery) hence the error.

With `dict.get()` you can get values from `dict` while having a default value in case the key is missing:

```
for i, joke in enumerate(parsed_json['jokes']):
    print(f"""joke #{i}: {joke.get('joke', '')}{joke.get('setup', '')} {joke.get('delivery', '')}""")
```

I printed the indexes just to be explicit, but you can use straight objects, and should use indexes only if necessary:

```
for joke in parsed_json['jokes']:
    print(f"""your joke sir: {joke.get('joke', '')}{joke.get('setup', '')} {joke.get('delivery', '')}""")
```